# Is this the correct way to call a sql database?

Tags: php, sql

Hey I was wondering if my ip_address is 0 and I want to check all tables that have a 0 ip_address and then execute a function of that. So something like this code:

```
    mysql_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass);
$ipzerouseroffline = mysql_db_query(db_name,"SELECT ip_address = '0' FROM user"); 

if ( $ipzerouseroffline == 0 ) {
         //THEN CODE GOES HERE
    }
```

Is that the correct way to write? If the ip_address is zero then the code passes.

Comment: It is NOT. Using the deprecated mysql extensions is not the correct way to do this, use mysqli or PDO instead: [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: No. Do not use mysql_* extension. Is deprecated.

Comment: There is no function `mysql_db_query()`.

Comment: What are you trying to determine with this query? Do you want all the users that have 0 ip_address, or do you want to know if there are any users with 0 ip_address?

Comment: I want all the users who have 0 ip_addres and then if ( users who have 0 ip_address) { code }

Comment: also isn't the sql itself wrong ? shouldn;t it be select * from ip_user where ip_Address='0'

Comment: I changed it oopps I was wondering about the if more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(db_server, db_user, db_pass, db_name);
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE ip_address = '0'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 //CODE
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to retrieve all records from the database and then check for the desired on client (=php) side. Imaging a situation where the table has 1 million records and only one record has `ip_address = 0`.